# XML Mind Editor. Как писать элементы GUI для XXE?

Tags: xml, gui, java, embedded

Кто-нибудь писал элементы *GUI* для *XML Mind Editor Professional*?

Не могу найти *Check Box List* среди элементов, которые можно подключать к *GUI* редактора.

Решил написать свой *Check Box List*. Отыскал мануал, где описывается, как добавлять новые компоненты, используя интерфейс, напсианный на *Java*: 
вот тут [как написать](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor//_distrib/doc/dev/gui.html), а тут [как подключить](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor//_distrib.../gui/index.htm).

Попробывал сначала подключить готовые элементы, к примеру, *AboutDialog*: всё меню описано в файлах конфигурации

(Toolbar.incl, Menu.incl, ConvertCommands.incl, ntc1_config.xxe и т.д.), а файл customize.xxe_gui должен содержать, куда наш *AboutDialog* будет подключаться.

Вот то, что должно выйти:
`customize.xxe_gui`

```
  <action name="aboutAction" label="_About This Document Editor">
    <class>com.xmlmind.xmleditapp.kit.part.AboutAction</class>
  </action>

  <menu name="docbookMenu"
        label="_DocBook" 
        insert="ifDefined(XXE.Edition.Unrestricted)after ##last">
     <action name="aboutAction" />
  </menu>
```

DocBook меню описано в нескольких файлах, вот один из фрагментов:

```
...
  <menu label="_DocBook"
    insert="ifDefined(XXE.Edition.Unrestricted)after ##last">
    ...
  </menu>
...
```

Но почему-то меню DocBook остаётся прежним, без изменений, как быть, может кто подскажет?